# Counter class extension

Tags: auto-increment

I am having a problem finding an elegant way to create a Counter() class that can:

- Feed in arbitrary number of keys and return a nested dictionary based on this list of keys.
- Increment for this nested dictionary is arbitrary as well.

For example:

```
counter = Counter()
for line in fin:
    if a:
        counter.incr(key1, 1)
    else:
        counter.incr(key2, key3, 2)
print counter
```

Ideally I am hoping to get the result looks like: {key1 : 20, {key2 : {key3 : 40}}}. But I am stuck in creating this arbitrary nested dictionary from list of keys. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to have the keys nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can subclass `dict` and create your own nested structure.

here's my attempt at writing such class :

```
class Counter(dict):
    def incr(self, *args):
        if len(args) < 2:
            raise TypeError, "incr() takes at least 2 arguments (%d given)" %len(args)

        curr = self

        keys, count = args[:-1], args[-1]

        for depth, key in enumerate(keys, 1):
            if depth == len(keys):
                curr[key] = curr.setdefault(key, 0) + count
            else:
                curr = curr.setdefault(key, {})


counter = Counter()

counter.incr('key1', 1)
counter.incr('key2', 'key3', 2)
counter.incr('key1', 7)
print counter #{'key2': {'key3': 2}, 'key1': 8}
```

Comment: @MengxiLu you said you'll aggregate these stats on different levels. with my code, numbers are stored on the outermost 'leaves' only; you should take care of that too. If you can spend some time and write your own tree-like structure that allows summation without traversing all the branches, it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

First, you can always fake the nested-keys thing by using a flat `Counter` with a "key path" made of `tuple`s:

```
counter = Counter()
for line in fin:
    if a:
        counter.incr((key1,), 1)
    else:
        counter.incr((key2, key3), 2)
```

But then you'll need to write a `str`-replacement—or, better, a wrapper class that implements `__str__`. And while you're at it, you can easily write an `incr` wrapper that lets you use exactly the API you wanted:

```
def incr(self, *args):
    super().incr(args[:-1], args[-1])
```

Alternatively, you can build your own `Counter`-like class on top of a nested `dict`. The code for `Counter` is written in pure Python, and [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l384) is pretty simple and readable.

From, your code, it looks like you don't have any need to access things like `counter[key2][key3]` anywhere, which means the first is probably going to be simpler and more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The only type of value that can exist in a `Counter` object is an int, you will not be able to represent a nested dictionary with a `Counter`.

Here is one way to do this with a normal dictionary (`counter = {}`).  First, to update increment the value for a single key:

```
counter[key1] = counter.setdefault(key1, 0) + 1
```

Or for an arbitrary list of keys to create the nested structure:

```
tmp = counter
for key in key_list[:-1]:
    tmp = tmp.setdefault(key, {})
tmp[key_list[-1]] = tmp.setdefault(key_list[-1], 0) + 1
```

I would probably turn this into the following function:

```
def incr(counter, val, *keys):
    tmp = counter
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        tmp = tmp.setdefault(key, {})
    tmp[keys[-1]] = tmp.setdefault(keys[-1], 0) + val
```

Example:

```
>>> counter = {}
>>> incr(counter, 1, 'a')
>>> counter
{'a': 1}
>>> incr(counter, 2, 'a')
>>> counter
{'a': 3}
>>> incr(counter, 2, 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> counter
{'a': 3, 'b': {'c': {'d': 2}}}
>>> incr(counter, 3, 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> counter
{'a': 3, 'b': {'c': {'d': 5}}}
```